# Culture changes in C# (Language changes)

Tags: c#

I have a string "Sunday", i want to change this Polish(Poland) . How can i change. I try to use Iformateprovider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some `DateTime` value `dateTime`, then you can use

```
dateTime.ToString("dddd")
```

to produce the day-of-week name in the current culture, or

```
dateTime.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo("da-DK"))
```

to produce it in another culture (here Danish (Denmark)).

If you want the "source" of these day names, use

```
string[] dayNamesPolish = (new CultureInfo("pl-PL")).DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
string[] dayNamesEnglish = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
```

To actually translate a string, do this:

```
string stringToTranslate = "Sunday";
int idx = Array.IndexOf(dayNamesEnglish, stringToTranslate);
string stringResult = dayNamesPolish[idx];
```

This works even though the `FirstDayOfWeek` is not the same in the two cultures (Polish has Monday as the first day).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need a different "resource" for each language:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756hydy4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

The "English" resource would contain the word "Sunday", the "Polish" resource the word "niedziela".

Comment: +0: This is answer to slightly different question - how do I localize my app in general. Name of the days of the week/month names are already avaialble.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `IFormatProvider" from culture you want. I.e.

```
 new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pl-pl").DateTimeFormat.DayNames[0]; // niedziela
```

Or to format current `DateTime` into just day of the week:

```
var day = String.Format(
   new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pl-pl"), 
   "Now:{0:dddd}", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: "Locale" is one thing; "language" another. In this case, I think the OP not only wanted to translate between "Sunday" and ""niedziela", but also "Yes" and "tak", "Cow" and "krowa", or any arbitrary word.  This is less discussed than standard i18n locale, but my link about [Localization Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756hydy4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) describes exactly how it's done in .Net.  Linux, on the other hand, would use [gettext()](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html).

Comment: @paulsm4, maybe... OP can decide what the question is actually about - both are answered now.

Answer (score 0):

see this National Language Support (NLS) API Reference , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx